# How to override hardcoded 'user-select: none' CSS property in customCardProps JSON column formatting so that text can be selected?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I've used [customCardProps in JSON column formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-advanced#custom-cards-on-hover) in a SharePoint document library column to display a table of column values when clicking on a button in a column.

This is convenient because the user can just view a table of relevant values, rather than having to scroll a long way to the right of the page to view all column values.

Unfortunately, Microsoft have hardcoded the [user-select CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) to `none`.

This means that users cannot highlight and select the text from my custom card.

I tried overriding the default styling of the particular elements with this JSON column formatting:

```css
"style": {
"-webkit-user-select": "text", 
"user-select": "text"
}
```

but it doesn't work, presumably because it is not a supported style:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#style

I am just hoping that, seeing as we are possibly close to AGI and the singularity, somebody might have a solution for how to make text selectable in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you placed the user-select in a wrong place. I put it at the style of the exact select-able field div in customCardProps, and it works well.

**Where is the style**

[image]

**You can now select particular text**

[image]

PS: My solution is not good, because it works only when I browse the list from Microsoft Lists platform, it doesn't work when you navigate to the list in its Sharepoint site. Sorry for that.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, confirming that it does not seem to work.  I did not understand your comments about your solution working in 'Microsoft Lists platform' but not in 'SharePoint site' - can you explain that more?  I always use the `?env=WebViewList` suffix on SharePoint lists, so they always appear in the 'Microsoft Lists' style for me.